# Sampling in case of imbalanced dataset

Tags: sampling, unbalanced-classes

From a course of AI for Medical Diagnosis, it is explained that validation and test sets should be balanced, 50-50 cases of both cases 0 and 1, so that the performance of the model can be assessed.

But one question arise, test set is suppossed to reflect reality, so it should be imbalanced meanwhile train set should be balanced to help the model to make a distinction between classes, is this approach correct?

Comment: There is no consensus that "balancing" is useful: [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)

Comment: I’m with Stephan that your thinking about the test set is the correct one, regardless of what the instructor says. (Note that this will not necessarily be the answer that gets full credit on the exam, which is unfortunate.) I am not on board with the idea of balancing the training data. This topic seems poorly understood outside of statistics, and “AI for Medical Diagnosis” does not sound like it is taught by the statistics department.

Comment: It's quite appalling how many didactic materials on the topic of AI and ML are nothing short of pure garbage. Find a new course.